# How to reduce high CPU usage with Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, spring-data-elasticsearch

I am using Elasticsearch 6.8.10 with Spring Boot 2.2.7 and Spring Data Elasticsearch.

I have streams of stats and trends data being stored in Kafka topics. These topics are read using Spring Kafka and stored into MongoDB and Elasticsearch for analysis and reporting. The problem I am having is that when the queues are being processed and the data is written to Elasticsearch, Elasticsearch CPU consumption is continuously around 250%. This leads to sporadic timeout errors across the application. I understand that indexing is an intensive operation but I am trying to understand what I can do to reduce the CPU usage.

Data:

- Approx stats queue items (1.2M)
- Stats document size (220 bytes)

The VM config details are:

- 4 CPU, 16GB Memory, 20GB disk (SSD)
- Running on a VM in Google Cloud Platform.
- VM only used for Elasticsearch

The Docker Elasticsearch config details:

- I am using single node (for the moment)

```
version: '2.4'
services:

  elasticsearch:
    container_name: elasticsearch
    image: 'docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:6.8.10'
    ports:
      - '9200:9200'
      - '9300:9300'
    mem_limit: 16GB
    environment:
      - discovery.type=single-node
      - cluster.name=docker-cluster
      - bootstrap.memory_lock=true
      - "ES_JAVA_OPTS=-Xms8g -Xmx8g"      
    ulimits:
      memlock:
        soft: -1
        hard: -1
      nofile:
        soft: 65536
        hard: 65536
    volumes:
      - 'esdata1:/usr/share/elasticsearch/data'
    restart: always

volumes:
  esdata1:
    driver: local
```

Example of Spring Stat document:

- Shards = 1, replicas = 0

```
@Document(indexName = "stats_test", type = "stat", shards = 1, replicas = 0)
public class EsStat {

    @Id
    @Field(type = FieldType.Keyword)
    private String id;

    @Field(type = FieldType.Keyword)
    private String entityOrRelationshipId;

    @Field(type = FieldType.Keyword)
    private String articleId;

    @Field(type = FieldType.Keyword)
    private String status;

    @Field(type = FieldType.Keyword)
    private String type;

    @JsonFormat(shape = JsonFormat.Shape.STRING, pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ")
    @Field(type = FieldType.Date, format = DateFormat.custom, pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ")
    private ZonedDateTime date;

    @JsonProperty("type")
    @Field(type = FieldType.Keyword)
    private String dataSource;

    // getter and setters 
}
```

Stats Spring repository:

- Indexing is done via Spring Data Elasticsearch repository:

```
public interface StatElasticsearchRepository extends ElasticsearchRepository<EsStat, String> {
}
```

Stats mapping:

```
{
  "stats": {
    "mappings": {
      "stat": {
        "properties": {
          "_class": {
            "type": "text",
            "fields": {
              "keyword": {
                "type": "keyword",
                "ignore_above": 256
              }
            }
          },
          "articleId": {
            "type": "keyword"
          },
          "dataSource": {
            "type": "keyword"
          },
          "date": {
            "type": "date",
            "format": "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ"
          },
          "entityOrRelationshipId": {
            "type": "keyword"
          },
          "id": {
            "type": "keyword"
          },
          "status": {
            "type": "keyword"
          },
          "type": {
            "type": "keyword"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

What can I do to identify why the CPU usage is so high and what can I do to reduce it?

Any advice or recommendations would be much appreciated. I'm happy to add more configuration/output if required.

Comment: you have a VM with 16GB only for ES, but limit it with: `"ES_JAVA_OPTS=-Xms8g -Xmx8g" `? How do you write your records to Elasticsearch With Spring Data Elasticsearch? Are you using repositories or the Elasticsearch template, do you do single or batch inserts?

Comment: Yes that's based on Elastic recommendations to set the heap to half of physical RAM (https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/heap-size.html). I am  using repositories. At the moment it's a single insert as each message (document) comes from Kafka.

Comment: repository or template? Inserting with the repository does a refresh after each insert.

Comment: Repository (add config above). When I look at topThreads (https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/cluster-nodes-hot-threads.html), I can see refresh. As there is lots of stats/trends data coming through (I think the defaut Kafka poll is 500 records), could it be that the refresh is just killing it? Is there anyway to prevent a refresh after an insert?

Comment: @Swordfish yes you can diable the refresh_interval (default is 1 sec), it's one of the most imp tips to improve indexing performance and mentioned in the links I mentioned in my answer

Answer (score 0):

So let's assume that it's the refresh call that is done after every `save()` -
It's quite easy to add a method to your repository that does a save without calling refresh:

First add a custom repository interface - I have it as a generic here:

*CustomRepository.java*:

```
public interface CustomRepository<T> {
    T saveNoRefresh(T entity);
}
```

The implementation would be:

*CustomRepositoryImpl.java*:

```
public class CustomRepositoryImpl<T> implements CustomRepository<T> {

    private final ElasticsearchOperations operations;

    public CustomRepositoryImpl(ElasticsearchOperations operations) {
        this.operations = operations;
    }

    @Override
    public T saveNoRefresh(T entity) {
        IndexQuery query = new IndexQueryBuilder().withObject(entity).build();
        operations.index(query, operations.getIndexCoordinatesFor(entity.getClass()));
        return entity;
    }
}
```

Your repository would change to:

```
public interface StatElasticsearchRepository 
  extends ElasticsearchRepository<EsStat, String>,
           CustomRepository<EsStat> {
}
```

The instead of the `save(T)` method call the `saveNoRefresh(T)` method of your repository.

Even better would be, if you can collect the data to batches of some size and then do a `saveAll()` call.

Comment: OK thanks P.J, I'll look at implementing this. The recommendation to batch is a good one, I think I can grab a batch of records from Kafka. Can the 'saveAll()' also be done without a refresh using the above mechanism as well?